# Callback for resource update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-put

This is my code below. It works properly when I use it in save method but in update, it gives me an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

**Services**

```
.factory('Details', function($resource, HostUrl){
        return $resource(HostUrl + '/api/v1/details/:id' , { id: '@id' } ,{
            update: { method: 'PUT' }
        });
    })
```

**Controller**

```
function updateStatus(details_id,status_id){

        var details = Details.get({id: details_id});
        details.status_id = status_id;
        details.$update({id: details_id})
            .$promise.then(function(data){
                // Success
            },
            function(error){
                // Error
            });
}
```

How to do this properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not need use promise, this solution wiil work

```
Details.update({id: details_id},  function (response) {
    //success function
}, function (response) {
   //error function
});
```

Comment: You can use promise too by using Details.update({id: details_id}).then(function (response) {
    //success function
}, function (response) {
   //error function
});